# snowflake convert_timezone does not work in pandas read sql

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, read-sql

convert_timezone works for me in the snowflake console:

```
select convert_timezone('America/Los_Angeles', '2022-05-25T14:27:30Z'::TIMESTAMP_TZ)
```

gives:

2022-05-25T07:27:30-07:00

but it does not work in pandas read sql:

```
pd.read_sql("select convert_timezone('America/Los_Angeles', '2022-05-25T14:27:30Z'::TIMESTAMP_TZ)", engine).values
```

gives:

array([[Timestamp('2022-05-25 21:27:30+0000', tz='UTC')]], dtype=object)

any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

When pandas receives TIMESTAMPs values from Snowflake it converts them to datetime64[ns]. It feels like in your case pandas converts the timestamp to UTC.

I suggest applying a conversion on the values in the dataframe using a series of methods like

```
.tz_localize("UTC").tz_convert("America/Los_Angeles"))
```

You can make sure that Snowflake generates the expected timestamp by going to the UI -> History and checking your query generated by Python Connector. In the query result section, you will be able to see the actual timestamp returned to pandas, highly likely it will be the expected one. Therefore, it should be adjusted on pandas.